# OkHttpClient throws exception after upgrading to OkHttp3

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using following lines of code to add a default header to all of my requests sent using Retrofit2:

```
private static OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
static {
    defaultHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "Application/JSON").build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });
}
```

After upgrading retrofit to beta-3 version, I had to upgrade OkHttp to OkHttp3 also (actually I just changed package names from okhttp to okhttp3, the library is included inside retrofit). After that I get exceptions from this line:

```
defaultHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor());
```

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>                                                                     at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:932)

---

> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

---

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have to use builder if you want to create OkHttp(3)Client object.

Try change this:

```
private static OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
```

To something like this:

```
  OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
       .addInterceptor(
           new Interceptor() {
             @Override
             public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                   Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                   .addHeader("Accept", "Application/JSON").build();
               return chain.proceed(request);
              }
           }).build();
```

Comment: Yes. it's working fine. thanks for perfect solution.

Comment: Hello, implementing above code says,... `incompatible types: required : retrofit2.Response <> ; Found: okHttp3.Response` ... ????

Comment: this is how is working in my case `OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder() .addInterceptor( new Interceptor() { @Override public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException { Request request = chain.request().newBuilder() .addHeader("Accept", "Application/JSON") .addHeader("Cookie", s) .addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=25000").build(); return chain.proceed(request); } }).build();` ... any idea why? Sorry, but I am new to Retrofit lib ...

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0"
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
```

You should probably use these versions. Just put them, **sync your gradle**, delete all imports, and try again.

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

import okhttp3.Request;

import okhttp3.Response;

import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;

import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for :)