# Android: Retrofit 2 get JSON value from XML

Tags: java, android, json, xml, retrofit

I'm using **Retrofit 2.1.0**. The return in XML is quite different. The JSON was placed inside the XML. I have searching about this for several hours but still not getting any idea how to retrieve the JSON value.

**XML :**

```
<string xmlns="http://www.something.com/">
[{"ReturnOK":"OK","Fullname":"Micheal","Userid":"4","strAppID":"9A380FFEACC444E8BE1E616F72A573C0","Phoneno":"1234567890"}]
</string>
```

**Retrofit Client:**

```
public static Retrofit getManager() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.HTTP.BASE_URL)
                .client(new OkHttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

**Login Interface:**

```
public interface LoginService {

    @GET(Constants.LOGIN.LOGIN_URL)
    Call<XMLString> doLogin(@Query(Constants.LOGIN.strAppID) String strAppID,
                        @Query(Constants.LOGIN.uname) String uname,
                        @Query(Constants.LOGIN.upassword) String upassword);
}
```

**XMLString :**

```
@Root(name="string", strict = false)
public class XMLString {

    private String reponse;


    public String getReponse() {
        return reponse;
    }

    public void setReponse(String reponse) {
        this.reponse = reponse;
    }
}
```

**Method :**

```
 private void loginProcess(String username, String password){

        LoginService endPoints = mManager.getManager().create(LoginService.class);
        Call<XMLString> call = endPoints.doLogin("1", username, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<XMLString>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<XMLString> call, Response<XMLString> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    XMLString xmlString = null;
                    try {
                        xmlString = call.execute().body();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    XMLString FromResponse = response.body();

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), FromResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<XMLString> call, Throwable t) {
                Utils.T(getActivity(), t.getMessage().toString());
            }
        });
      }
```

**Error :**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: app.test.com.junn, PID: 12501
>                     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>                         at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1128)
>                         at app.test.com.junn.controller.RestManager.getManager(RestManager.java:29)
>                         at app.test.com.junn.ui.fragment.LoginDialogFragment.loginProcess(LoginDialogFragment.java:100)
>                         at app.test.com.junn.ui.fragment.LoginDialogFragment.onClick(LoginDialogFragment.java:83)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Remove `requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");` this

Comment: @android_griezmann, done but still same error

Comment: Please show the code for the click method.

Comment: @MoGa update as requested.

Comment: It seems that you need to get first the content of your xml and then parse the JSON

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/37899858/4848308, Maybe this helps you to the right path

Comment: @GueorguiObregon, the first xml dont have tag, how to get the JSON ?

Comment: In your xml response your tag is `<string`. You must the get the content inside your `<string>` tag. The content is actually the json that you want to parse

Comment: @GueorguiObregon, i will try that.

Comment: @GueorguiObregon, I still failed to call the elements inside the XML file. Could you please see updated questions.

Comment: Are you getting the same error message?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/34973916/4848308.

Comment: @GueorguiObregon yeah, I still getting same error message

Comment: Did you try replacing your `new OkHttpClient();` with 

    `new OkHttpClient.Builder()
           .addInterceptor(
               new Interceptor() {
                 @Override
                 public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                       Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                       .addHeader("Accept", "Application/JSON").build();
                   return chain.proceed(request);
                  }
               }).build();` ?

Comment: Yeah, I do. But still failure. The Body response is null.

Comment: Well that is a different issue :)

Comment: @GueorguiObregon, I dont think so.