# Add headers to the interceptor on retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, okhttp

Since I need use Retrofit 2 and I have the need to Log what's happening behind the request, so the solution is add a request interceptor. I added an interceptor I take from okhttp wiki [page](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors), I also add some other changes as my needs and set it to the okhttp client at build stage but it did not work as I expected. for my surprise when I set my custom Interceptor to the okhttp client the GsonConverter is not able to parse the response json into java objects.

Here is the code from my Interceptor

```
public class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private final static String TAG = "RI";

private HashMap<String, String> headersMap = null;
public LoggingInterceptor(HashMap<String, String> headers) {
    this.headersMap = headers;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

    Request request = chain.request();
    Request.Builder reqBuilder = request.newBuilder();
    Log.e(TAG, "Headers on the map -> " + headersMap.size());
    for (String header : headersMap.keySet()) {
        reqBuilder.addHeader(header, headersMap.get(header));
    }

    request = reqBuilder.build();
    long timeRequest = System.nanoTime();
    Log.d(TAG, String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Sending %s with %s", request.url(), request.headers()));

    Response response = chain.proceed(request);

    Log.d(TAG, "<<<=========================================>>>");
    long timeResponse = System.nanoTime();
    Log.d(TAG, String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Receiving %s in %s%n%s", response.request().url(), ((timeResponse - timeRequest)/1e6d), response.headers()));
    Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + response.body().string());
    Log.d(TAG, "Code: " + response.code());

    return response;
}
```

}

And here is how I add it to the Okhttp client

```
private OkHttpClient createHttpClient(){
    if(client == null){

        String strUserAgent = "tm-vc=" + BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE + "-devid=" + (getDeviceID().isEmpty() ? "0" : getDeviceID());
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put(HEADER_ACCEPT,      "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        headers.put(HEADER_USER_AGENT,  strUserAgent);
        String cookie =  getSessionCookie();
        if(cookie != null && !cookie.isEmpty())
            headers.put(HEADER_COOKIE,  cookie);
        
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor(headers));
        builder.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);
        client = builder.build();
    }
    return client;
}
```

To test what I said I just need to comment this line `builder.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor(headers));`, if you comment the line, the retrofit onResponse is called and succeded(works, json gets parsed), if not onFailure is called.

SO what do I missing on me own Interceptor implementation?

WHAT IS THE QUESTION ITSELF?
**How do I add headers to the request using Interceptors?**

Yes, I can do with annotations but the headers's value would be static.

**NOTE:** Im using the totally renew Retrofit 2.

Comment: Why you dont use HttpLoggingInterceptor? https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: @robert-banyai It fails too, and also I need to add headers to it

Comment: Sorry, but still dont understand your problem, you can add more then one interceptor to your client. I use the same way, and works perfect.

Comment: @RobertBanyai now i get it, HttpLogging interceptor failed because the version did not match with the okhttp version. Now it works

Comment: when you do `Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + response.body().string());` you are consuming the body.

Comment: I don't think it was a duplicates...

Comment: @njzk2 had the answer

Comment: if you don't want to rebuild a `Response` as in the linked question, though, you can simply use the `HttpLoggingInterceptor` for logging, and add another interceptor for injecting the headers.

Comment: Ok I get it, @njzk2 I think that is a better approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HttpLoggingInterceptor** with **Retrofit 2** as follows

**1) Api Client**

```
// imports
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

---

// Method to create instance of Service
public ApiService getService() {

    // Interceptor to Log the Request
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    // Level.BODY prints Urls, Params and Response
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    // Create the Client
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    // Initialize retrofit instance
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    // Creates the instance of Web Service Representation
    return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
}
```

**2) Gradle dependencies**

```
// Retrofit 2 dependency
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
// GSON for Parsing into POJOs
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
// Logging Interceptor to Log the  Request
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
// OK HTTP dependency (for Compatibility)
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

**3) Likewise you can add your own customization (e.g., Headers) to Retrofit**

Comment: your solution works but in that way I can't inject the requests headers in the request, and in this [example](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) says it's possible. I tried to copy that sample and add some functionality but it did not work.

Comment: Checkout this one: *[See if this could solve your issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35024248/6213557)
Note: Interceptors are ordered.