# Android Retrofit Bearer Token

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit2 to consume the json. 
when I do login a bearer token is generated and saved into SharedPrefenences. 
I want to use this bearer token as Authentication header. 
and everytime I used it the response message was "Unauthorized"

```
 here's my Request: 

                @GET("user/wishlist")
       Call<WishListModel> getWishList(@Header("Authorization") String BearerToken);
```

and here's the call:

```
      Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("URL").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
      RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
      Call<WishListModel> call = requestInterface.getWishList("Bearer "+token);
```

Comment: requestInterface.getWishList("Bearer "+token);// why are you concatenating? 
is "Bearer" part of the token?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding header to all request with Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605711/adding-header-to-all-request-with-retrofit-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add header using OkHttp interceptor.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("parameter", "value").build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(url).client(httpClient.build()).build();
```

Then use the retrofit instance to invoke your call.

Please refer [Adding header to all request with Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605711/adding-header-to-all-request-with-retrofit-2)