# How to resolve the error of getting response 400 while signup through api in android retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

When I used to click on submit button by filing all the details I am getting response 400. So can you Please help me to get out of it.
Below There is my Postman.
I'm using the library retrofit 2.5.0

My POJO Class

```
public class Signup {

@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;

@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;

@SerializedName("role")
@Expose
private String role;

public Signup(String email, String password, String role) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
}
```

Here is my Interface in which i send only email, role and password

My Interface

```
public interface SignupApiService {

@POST("users")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Signup> savePost(@Field("email") String email,
                      @Field("password") String password,
                      @Field("role") String role);
}
```

This is My Java Class

```
public class SignupClient {

private static SignupClient mInstance;
private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://74.207.233.160/api/v1/";

private SignupClient(){
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static synchronized SignupClient getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new SignupClient();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public SignupApiService getApi() {
    return retrofit.create(SignupApiService.class);
}
}
```

And This My Main Activity

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Call<Signup> call = SignupClient
                        .getInstance().getApi()
                        .savePost(email, password, role);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Signup>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Signup> call, Response<Signup> response) {
                        int statusCode = response.code();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("SignupActivity", "onResponse" +statusCode);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Signup> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

PostMan
[image: My Postam]

Comment: _The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server, often something simple like a request to load a web page, was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it_

Comment: How i can resolve it. Can u help me please

Comment: Do you want to send image or simple data?

Comment: sample data i want

Comment: When you send data using Post man does it work?

Comment: yes it works. u can use the above api

Comment: Then in postman and your code why the key names are different? What its indicate?

Comment: But i program i am getting response 400

Comment: Did you use the same key ?

Comment: the key is user[email], it indicates the key

Comment: when i use the same key i am getting response 500

Comment: user[email] means form params for creating new user

Comment: After using the _user[email]_ key and getting 500 internal server error that means you need to add header _header("accept", "application/json")_ to your _RequestBuilder_

Comment: that were i want to add. in interface or any other class

Comment: Here _retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()_

Comment: that means above that or below that

Comment: .header is getting error

Comment: _.addHeader_ will something like

Comment: .addHeader i am getting error

Comment: Try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605711/adding-header-to-all-request-with-retrofit-2) and [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header)

Comment: Then also i am getting same error

Comment: Here is my program link "https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ACn8qHxsHULn_P4dOV0KZ8bkRqg9Cqx/view?usp=sharing"

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
public interface SignupApiService {

@POST("users")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Signup> savePost(@Field("user[email]") String email,
                      @Field("user[password]") String password,
                      @Field("user[role]") String role);
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error 'Only one encoding annotation is allowed' and showing error at the line ".savePost(email, password, role);" in signup Activity

Comment: Then also i am getting the error 'Multipart method must contain at least one @Part' And showing error at the same line in signup Activity

Comment: Here is my Program link "https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ACn8qHxsHULn_P4dOV0KZ8bkRqg9Cqx/view?usp=sharing"

Comment: Here is my program link "drive.google.com/file/d/13ACn8qHxsHULn_P4dOV0KZ8bkRqg9Cqx/…" –