# Attribute must be constant in Retrofit @Header

Tags: java, android, header, retrofit2

I want to pass a header to each POST request in a retrofit api . Since i have lots of methods hear, i can't copy/paste the header information for every method.

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    String[] header = {"Accept:application/json",
                       "apiKey:12345",
                       "Content-Type:application/json"};

    @Headers(header)
    @POST("signup?")
    Call<SignupResponse> createUser(@Body SignupData signupData);

    @Headers(header)
    @POST("another")
    ....
}
```

The header variable in **@HEADER** creates this error:

> Attribute must be constant

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Is there any problem if you remove, `Accept` and `Content-Type` part? Just try with `@Header()` which requires `String` type not `String[]` use ("apiKey:12345"). And also why don't you try Retrofit's [HttpInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35024248/5180017)?

Comment: The **SOLUTION** was the link which @Shashanth recommended. I should use the HttpClient interceptor to add headers to retrofit obj.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@Headers({"Accept:application/json",
            "apiKey:12345",
            "Content-Type:application/json"})
@POST("signup?")
    Call<SignupResponse> createUser(@Body SignupData signupData);
```

Comment: Actually i want to avoid write the 3 lines in `@Headers()` for each method. is it possible?

Comment: There is no alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
@Headers({"Accept:application/json",
         "apiKey:12345",
         "Content-Type:application/json"})
@POST("another")
```

See the "Header Manipulation" section of [the Retrofit documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).